# How to Simplify Quantity Selection for Configurable Products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

Hello Magento Community,

I'm facing a challenge with Magento 2's configurable products. My store sells products B2B in different quantity lengths, and I use configurable products to offer various length options (e.g., 10m, 50m). The issue arises when customers select a length variant (like 50m) from a dropdown menu but then also have to specify the quantity in the cart, leading to confusion.

Is there a way to streamline this process so that when a customer selects a variant (like 50m), it automatically sets the quantity in the cart, eliminating the need for a second quantity selection? I'm looking for a solution that provides a smooth and intuitive shopping experience. My aim is to have the 10 meter option with a unique SKU (SKU-10) and the 50 meter option as well with a unique SKU (SKU-50) so that I can manage them differently in my ERP system later.

Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this in Magento 2 would be greatly appreciated.